# Airflow - Slow Web UI

Tags: airflow

I have installed Airflow 2.4.2 on my local machine for learning purposes. When I open Airflow Web UI, the response is very slow. Sometimes, it errors out with the response "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE". Other times, when it loads, it takes about 10 seconds to load the page whenever a link on the web UI is clicked.

https://share.cleanshot.com/GSxb5h57

I tried it with localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080 and myhostname:8080, and all of them resulted in the same slow response.

Is there some customisation/tweaking needed to improve the Web UI response time?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the log of your webserver? and which executor you are using? local executor, celery or sequential?

Comment: I had a similar problem on Mac. However, on AWS t2.large Ubuntu, it works fast. I think that should do with the machine, network, and firewall.